# How to stop Objectify from returning cached values?

Tags: objectify

I'm saving an object with Objectify like this:

```
Thing th = new Thing();
th.identifier = thingId;
th.name = thingName;
th.json = thingData;
ofy().save().entity(thing);
pResponse.setStatus(200);
pResponse.getWriter().println("OK");
```

I verify using the GAE datastore browser that the value has been updated in the database. I'm running locally. Then I load all things like this:

```
Map<String, List<Thing>> responseJsonMap = new HashMap<String, List<Thing>>();
List<Thing> things = ofy().load().type(Thing.class).list();         
responseJsonMap.put("things", things);
pResponse.setContentType("application/json");
try {
    GSON.toJson(responseJsonMap, pResponse.getWriter());
} ...
```

What I get back is the data that existed before the save. I have tried turning caching off on the entity and calling `ofy().clear()` but neither work. If I restart my server or wait long enough, the saved data comes through. I have also tried adding `.now()` after the save, but it's not necessary since I can verify in the datastore that the action has completed. I really would like to be able to load the data I just saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm use Objectify4.0b1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'm doing wrong is not reading the manual and forgetting a step.

> Objectify requires a filter to clean up any thread-local transaction
>   contexts and pending asynchronous operations that remain at the end of
>   a request. Add this to your WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Well, good thing to check if you're getting cached values that you really don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the ObjectifyFilter issue, what you are most likely seeing is the eventually consistent nature of queries in the datastore.

See this:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: That is a good thing to look out for, but since I'm running locally, I haven't hit this issue -- yet.